# Count days between two days

Tags: date

Can you explain me this code

```
if month>2 then
  month:=month+1
else begin
  month:=month+13;
  year:=year-1;
end;
DaysFromZero:=trunc(36525*year/100+306*month/10+day);
```

Trunc returns the integer part of X, which is always smaller than (or equal to) X in absolute value. For example trunc(123.5) would give us 123.

I know it's somehow related to Zero year https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year) but I still don't get how it works.

So the difference between DaysFromZero using two sets of dates gives me number of days between those two dates and i want to know why...

Comment: 1 year = 365.242199 days. So here we have 36525*year/100 - number of days from the year 0 to current year. 1 month =
30.4368499 days. So I guess we have 306*month/10 here - number of days from the 1st month till current one.  So having two different sets we can know how many days there were between the 1st day of year 0 and each of dates. So the difference is obviously the number of days between those dates

Answer (score 0):

- 1 year = 365.242199 days.  So here we have 36525*year/100 - number of
  days from the year 0 to current year.
- 1 month = 30.4368499 days.  So    I guess we have 306*month/10 here -
  number of days from the 1st month    till current one.

So having two different sets we can know how many days there were between the 1st day of year 0 and each of dates. 
So the difference is obviously the number of days between those dates